How to get text from image correctly
Belowing is my image. I want to read text from it. And I found a software called tesseract. I installed it and tried. But I failed to work it out.
My Image
Someone can help me, how can I get the correct result?

please add the image to the question and also what you are trying to do. Edit the title to a summary of your task. Include the error message in the post itself

I added the figure of error message

I meant the image you are doing the analysis on, as well as your main code where you are calling the function

I uploaded some new stuffs as you said.

I also want to know, is my image can be much better recognized by computer? I mean by some image processing method.

What do you want to do? Get the text in the image?

Yes, I mean get text from image correctly.

You need to install tesseract for this, have you already done that?

I advise you to close this question and post another one with your specific problem. If you want to identify text in your image, ask a question about that and include the tesseract tag as well. Your post currently does not include anything related to detecting text in images. The snippet that you included is about deskewing an image.

Yes, I use that one to recognize this image, but I failed. So I tried to use some auxilary image processing technique like above to pre-processing this image.

ok, actually, this rotating stuff is also a question. I will try to open another question.

I'll post a very minimal answer

It's fine. Thanks in advance.

Consider accepting my answer whenever you see that it works for you.

Again, question is very basic. You can find tonnes of examples on the internet. Just google something like OCR or pytesseract. You need to get a working installation of tesseract on your machine. Follow the steps here.
The code below can do this without any pre-processing:
import cv2
import pytesseract
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = "C:/Program Files/Tesseract-OCR/tesseract.exe"
im = cv2.imread("text.jpg")
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(im, config='-l eng --psm 7')
print(text)

The result:
1.331 dBm

Hope this helps you further. If you post another question, please make sure to stick to a point and include relevant information in your question.

Thank you for your advice. I want to ask what is your config parameter for?

Check this: https://muthu.co/all-tesseract-ocr-options/

Ok. Thank you very much. Bro. A red flower for you :D
